# How to increase space between two columns in moderncv

Tags: spacing, moderncv, columns

I was able to increase width of the column but I want to increase the space between `\cventry` that is date and the contents.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 4):

This length is controlled by `\separatorcolumnwidth` which is set to

```
\setlength{\separatorcolumnwidth}{0.025\textwidth}
```

in [`moderncvstyleclassic.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/moderncvstyleclassic.sty). Update this in the preamble to suit your needs. Below is the default (left) output compared to setting it to `.2\textwidth` (using [`template.tex`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/examples/template.tex)):

[image]