# How to increase the horizontal space between moderntimeline and the text?

Tags: moderncv, moderntimeline

This question is related to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159715/how-to-increase-space-between-two-columns-in-moderncv).

I am using [this](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/examples/moderncv-with-modern-timeline/prmmmvtvfxsn) template and, I am not able to change the space between the date and the content by changing `\separatorcolumnwidth`.

How can I do so?

Comment: Please  show us the code you tried so far. Do not link to an webside one has to log in to see something ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the command `\setlength{\separatorcolumnwidth}{0.25\textwidth}` or `\setlength{\separatorcolumnwidth}{3cm}` to your preamble. Change the values used for your needs ....

With the folowing MWE

```
\documentclass{moderncv}

\usepackage{moderntimeline}
\moderncvtheme{classic}
\tlmaxdates{2007}{2012}

\setlength{\separatorcolumnwidth}{0.25\textwidth} % 0.025 <=============

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}


\begin{document}
\tlcventry{2010}{0}{I'm still doing this!}{}{}{}{}
\tlcventry{2009}{2010}{Then I did something else.}{}{}{}{}
\tlcventry{2009}{2009}{I did something cool for just one year.}{}{}{}{}
\tlcventry{2007}{2009}{A regular entry}{}{}{}{}
\end{document}
```

you get the wished result:

[image]

Comment: When this code is put inside `main` it works, but not when it is placed inside `moderncvstyleclassic.sty`. Why is it so?

Comment: @Majis depends on the place wher you placed it in `moderncvstyleclassic.sty`. But if possible do not change that file! Placed in your cv you can be sure it is called last and therefore is working ...